# Dual of $L^\infty(I,H^1(M))$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

What is the dual of $L^\infty(I,H^1(M))$?

Any references?
Where $H^1(M)$ is Sobolev space, and $I$ is some interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and $M$ is a compact manifold, like the $n$-dimensional torus.